# I want to get the list of users who were present in the club from 10 AM to 12 PM using an SQL query in Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, lumen

thank you for reading this issue. please help me with the below issue

I want to user list which users in the club at the time between

- 022-11-07 11:32:48 - 2022-11-07 12:32:48

below is data store in DB

- In Time--------------------Out Time----------------- be show in result
- 2022-11-07 11:32:48  -  2022-11-07 12:32:48     => 1
- 2022-11-07 10:32:48  -  2022-11-07 11:33:00     => 1
- 2022-11-07 12:32:00  -  2022-11-07 13:32:00     => 1
- 2022-11-07 11:45:00  -  2022-11-07 12:15:00     => 1
- 2022-11-07 10:00:00  -  2022-11-07 13:00:00     => 1
- 2022-11-07 09:30:00  -  2022-11-07 11:30:00     => 0
- 2022-11-07 12:35:00  -  2022-11-07 13:32:48     => 0

```
$activity = Activity::findOrFail($activity_id);

$users = User::whereHas('activities', function ($q) use ($activity) {
   $q->where('activities.activity_id', $activity->activity_id);
})->whereHas('bookingActivities', function ($query) use ($booking) {
   $query->whereNull('cancelled_by')
   ->whereBetween('bookingActivities.entry_time', [$booking->entry_time, $booking->exit_time])
   ->orWhereBetween('bookingActivities.exit_time', [$booking->_entry_time, $booking->exit_time]);
})->paginate();
```

I have add the query and it will give me 4 result it Should be 5

I am working on the lumen framework. i am use eloquent for get data  I want to Logic or query to get all the user which in club in 10 to 11 but in my query 2022-11-07 10:00:00 - 2022-11-07 13:00:00 => 1 record not get. i try to get user using between the entry time and exit time but 2022-11-07 10:00:00 - 2022-11-07 13:00:00 => 1 record not get i in query but it should in.

please help me to how can i add the query so i can get expect result.

thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Are you really using both Laravel 4 and 5, which are both totally outdated?

Comment: currently, I am working on the lumen framework but it is use eloquent so no issue with the version, I want to query this.

in this query 2022-11-07 10:00:00 - 2022-11-07 13:00:00 => 1 record not get because of this is not between the entry time and exit time but the person in the club

Comment: Which entry is missing?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, please adjust the tagging

Comment: Your questions doesn't indicate all the elements we need to find what is wrong with your query (we need to know how are your model structured and the relations you mention). But your problem may be on your activity or bookingActivity models, since you're using whereHas if the user has no activity it won't be retreive by your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query works by the logic that

either the user *logged in* between your Start `($booking->entry_time)` and End (`$booking->exit_time`)

```
->whereBetween('bookingActivities.entry_time', [$booking->entry_time, $booking->exit_time])
```

or *logged out* between the Start and End of your search timeframe.

```
->orWhereBetween('bookingActivities.exit_time', [$booking->entry_time, $booking->exit_time])
```

You are missing one value because in your example a User entered before your Start and left after the End of your searched timeframe. Neither of your time conditions fits that case.

To solve it you can put the user's entry_time and exit_time into perspective to the Start value of your searched timeframe.

By adding for example the following condition, you search for all users who *logged in* before and exit after the Start value of your searched timeframe.

```
->orWhere(function ($query) {
       $query->where('bookingActivities.entry_time', '<', $booking->entry_time)
       ->where('bookingActivities.exit_time', '>', $booking->entry_time);
            })
```